# Java XML Parsing, read's values into array correctly then overwrites entire array with last values?

Tags: java, xml, arrays, overwrite

I'm making a simple game, and loading an XML file with weapon stats into an array of weapons to be used in game. The stats and weapon objects are all correctly read and populated until the 'try' statement ends and then the entire array of weapons is re-written with the values of the last read weapon element. I can not for the life of me figure out why it decides to re-write everything suddenly, help would be greatly appreciated as I feel it's a rookie mistake!

```
    private void populateWeaponArray(NodeList listOfWeapons){

    String weaponName;
    int[] stats = new int[10];
    int weaponClass;
    boolean twoHanded;

    try{
        for(int i=0;i<listOfWeapons.getLength();i++){

            //Get individual weaponNode
            Node weaponNode = listOfWeapons.item(i);

            //Convert to element to provide more methods and access node information
            //Element is just an interface that inherits from node
            Element weaponElement = (Element) weaponNode;

            //Retrieve Attribute Values level, class
            stats[9] = Integer.valueOf(weaponElement.getAttribute("level"));
            weaponClass = Integer.valueOf(weaponElement.getAttribute("class"));

            //Get a list of all stats of weapon
            NodeList statList = weaponElement.getChildNodes();

            //populate the stat[] with all numbers
            for(int s=0;s<9;s++){
                stats[s] = Integer.valueOf(statList.item(s).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }

            //Retrieve name and twohanded from xml
            weaponName = statList.item(9).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            twoHanded = Boolean.valueOf(statList.item(10).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());

            //Construct weapon object from values
            weapons[i] = new Weapon(weaponName, weaponClass, twoHanded, stats);  
            System.out.println(weapons[i]); //Weapon objects here all display correctly
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("weaponHandler  " + e.getMessage());
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<weapons.length;i++){
        System.out.println(weapons[i]); //Suddenly Weapon objects here all have the same stats?
    }
```

Calling the overwritten toString method of each weapon before the end of the try{} all reveals them to have the correct stats from the XML, however the moment the block has ended they all have the same stats. If you need to know anything else just gimmie a shout, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: At the time, I couldn't see what I was doing wrong despite being provided the answer - I just didn't understand. A year later, I log back in and see this question, I completely understand! Thanks again for answering - I roll my eyes at my own question when I read it tonight. Glad to know there's a supportive community out there for beginners :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new stats array inside the loop.

Comment: Ok seriously?! That actually worked, thanks a bunch! This might be another simple question but could you possibly enlighten me as to why this works? Solved the problem in one though, brilliant, thanks :)

Comment: You were reusing one and the same stats array for all weapons. Shared. And filling it with each weapon's stats in succession.